# How should I understand these phrases in this paper on orbit transfers?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, nasa, lagrangian-points, soho

I am studying this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/234416114_Sun-Earth_L1_Region_Halo-to-Halo_Orbit_and_Halo-to-Lissajous_Orbit_Transfers) on orbital mechanics and can't understand the meaning of some terms related to mathematics (perhaps because my native language doesn't have such terms). I created the [same thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625524/explanation-of-some-phrases-from-scientific-article) on math.stackexchange.com and there I was recommended to duplicate this question here.

1.

> The user constructs a targeting scheme [in the program] consisting
>   of independent targeting variables (components of the impulses) and
>   dependent variables (targeting goals). Generally a scheme is
>   constructed such that the number of independent variables equals the
>   number of dependent variables to provide the differential corrector
>   [DC] with a '**square' problem** to solve.

'square' problem – here does the author mean a system of equations where the number of unknown variables is equal to the number of equations in the system?

2.

> Swingby [the programm] propagates trajectories numerically with **full
>   operations-level force modeling** invoked.

I don't have any ideas.

3.

> In his development of the **third-order solution to the equations of
>   motion** for LPOs, Richardson shows...

I don't understand the phrase "third-order solution". The author is talking about "solution of a third-order equations"?

4.

> In summary, given the four parameters of the desired Lissajous, the
>   **third-order theory** yields the state coordinates of the desired target
>   insertion point.

Is the author here talking about a theory based on equations (probably differential) of the third order?

5.

> The angle *phi* is measured in the RLP [a reference frame] xy-plane
>   clockwise from the -x-axis, and the angle *psi* is **the phase with
>   respect to the z-axis**.

I don't have any ideas.

6.

> However the departure burn and the Z-burn are differentially corrected
>   simultaneously, **making for a 3-by-3 differential correction
>   problem**.

3-by-3 problem – could it be a system of three equations with three unknown variables?

7.

> ... position calculated by the **third order approximation**.

This is a phraseology (like the phrase "zeroth-order approximation" for a very inaccurate solution) or reference to third order polynomium approximation?

Answer (score 1):

Some of this appears to be more colloquial than strict math.  Here are my guesses

'square problem' - just means N inputs and N outputs requires a square matrix for transformation

'operations-level forcemodeling' -- crank up all the computers and software on hand

'third-order equations /theory' - most likely taking the analytic equations and using the first three terms in a Taylor or Fourier series expansion.

'phase with respect to Z-axis'  -- since you mention Lissajous figures earlier, this probably means  the periodic motion along the z-axis described as $z = sin(\omega t + \psi)$

'three by three' - you are correct- another square matrix of size 3,3 .